# sympy integral wrong outside of values between 0 and 2pi for |cos x |?

Tags: python, sympy, trigonometry, integral, absolute-value

I have come across strange outputs for sympy's `integrate` when it comes to **|cos(x)|** (I am restricting x to real numbers). Based on both the indefinite integral and definite integrals, sympy seems to gives correct results only for the [0,2pi] interval (disregarding definite integrals whose boundaries are in the same continuous chunks of the primitive function of |cos(x)|).

```
from sympy import *
x = Symbol("x", real=True)
eq = abs(cos(x))
print("Integrand:")
display(eq)
eqI = integrate(eq, x )
print("Indefinite integral according to sympy:")
display(eqI)
```

As for definite integrals: all of the following should result in 2, but only the first one results in the correct value (the second one outputs 0, the last one -2, which cannot be correct for a definite integral of a positive-values-only function if *a < b*).

```
## correct:
a = pi/2
b = 3*pi/2
print(f"Definite integral according to sympy from {a} to {b}:", integrate(eq, (x, a, b)))

## incorrect:
print("")
a = -pi/2
b = pi/2
print(f"Definite integral according to sympy from {a} to {b}:", integrate(eq, (x, a, b)))
    
## incorrect:
print("")
a = 7*pi/2
b = 9*pi/2
print(f"Definite integral according to sympy from {a} to {b}:", integrate(eq, (x, a, b)))
```

My question is: Is this down to some aspect of the design of sympy I am not aware of, or is this a bug? If the former, I would expect it to throw a *NotImplementedError* for values it is not designed to handle instead of returning an incorrect value.

For quick reference, here are the graphs of the original function (in yellow) and a discontinuous (red) and continuous (blue) primitive function thereof:

[image: graphs]

(Note: I am using sympy version 1.5.1, but I checked the incorrectly calculated definite integrals on version 1.6 and they are still wrong.)

Comment: This is a bug in sympy

Comment: Better to report it on github: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up!

Comment: Now that I searched the issues on github, nr [15402](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/15402) covers this bug. What I found is that as of sympy version 1.6.1: 
(i) `Integral` with `evalf()`, but not `doit()` seems to work correctly for me (in line with the still open issue 15402),
(ii) `integrate` does not.